# Hibernate - allow references to unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to save records of a table that have relations with other tables, but I need to allow null references, without saving the sub-object.

This is the situation: class A has related object b and c, when I save an A instance I want to save null reference of b and c.

The table structure is the following:

```
id (PK) | id_tr_inner_costs | release_id | requirement_id | task_id | hours | total_cost
```

requirement_id and/or task_id can be null, and should be set so in this situation.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'save null reference'?  Perhaps you could add your table structure, and what you want the column values to be?

Comment: @sharakan: Hi, thanks for the answer. Thi is my table structure:  id, 
id_tr_inner_costs,
release_id,
requirement_id (this references another table and could be null),
task_id  (this references another table and this could be null),
hours,
total_cost

Comment: @JohnProgrammer you should edit your question to have the table structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will set those ID's to null if the references are null at the time of saving.  So something like this:

```
A instanceOfA = ...;
instanceOfA.setRelease(null);
instanceOfA.setTask(null);
session.save(instanceOfA);
```

should result in you having a row in the A table that has `NULL` for both `release_id` and `task_id`.

This is detailed very lightly in the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-entitiesvalues):

> With the exception of collections, all built-in Hibernate types
>   support null semantics.

ie, if something is null in Java, then it will be null in the database.